# Scrapy Spider Crawl 0 pages

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I'm trying to extract json data with Scrapy from a website, but i'm facing some issues, like when i run my spider, gives no error and says that crawled 0 pages. I also use the command to store de output to json file to see the output.

The following code is my spider:

```
import scrapy

class WineSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "SpidyWine"
i = 0
url = 'https://maiscarrinho.com/api/search?q=vinho&pageNumber=%s&pageSize=10'
start_urls = [url % 1]

def parse(self, response):
data = json.loads(response.body)
for item in data['results']:
    yield {
        'Image': item.get('image')
    }
if data['Image']:
    i = i + 1
    yield scrapy.Request(self.url % i, callback=self.parse)
```

And my class of items:

```
import scrapy

class MaiscarrinhoItem(scrapy.Item):

 image = scrapy.Field()
 price = scrapy.Field()
 supermarket = scrapy.Field()
 promotion = scrapy.Field()
 wineName = scrapy.Field()
 brand = scrapy.Field()
```

For now, i'm just using the Image field in my spider to get things more easier.
Also, my ideia when i wrote the if statement in my spider was to 'deal' with the infinite scorlling, when the json api has 'Image' means that that page have content.

[Output in Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrHI4.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post your run log? You can get it by `scrapy crawl myspider &> output.log`

Comment: @Granitosaurus 
I edited my post and you have the image, since with your command my file was empty.

Answer (score 1):

You did everything right except a very small mistake.

The field name which contains the image is `Image` and not `image`

Try :

```
yield {
    'Image': item.get('Image')
}
```

There is probably something also wrong with your `ITEM_PIPELINES` in settings.py file

[image: Working with python requests]

[image: Works even with scrapy:]

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work. When i run the command: Scrapy crawl SpidyWine -o output.json it stores "["

Comment: Can you also change you scrapy field to 'Image = scrapy.Field()` and try?
If this doesn't work, comment your  pipeline `MaiscarrinhoItem` in `ITEM_PIPELINES` from settings file and run.

Comment: I changed the field like you suggested but didn't worked. And about pipeline are you talking about ITEM_PIPELINES in settings.py ? By default that piece of code are already in comments.

Comment: Can you post the lines of your `ITEM_PIPELINES`from settings.py file?
If you use requests to do the same thing as to what your spider does, it gives the image paths.

Comment: The following code is what i have about `ITEM_PIPELINES` in my settings.py:
`# Configure item pipelines
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
#ITEM_PIPELINES = {
#    'Maiscarrinho.pipelines.SomePipeline': 300,
#}`

What kind of shell are you using ? i can't reproduce what you show in your images.

Comment: `zsh` but that shouldn't matter as long as scrapy is working fine. try 2 things:
1. things I did in the 2nd image + screenshot
2. Uncomment pipeline and run

Answer (score 1):

Well answering to my question and after digging into my code after some time... I realized it was about identation errors and some errors of syntaxe.

Another point was the pipeline, i forgot to change de last name to the real name of my pipeline, so instead of having `'Maiscarrinho.pipelines.SomePipeline': 300` now i have `'Maiscarrinho.pipelines.MaiscarrinhoPipeline': 300`

The bellow code are extracting the images like i want, but there is one problem yet. Since the page have infinite scrolling i have a condition to evaluate if there is an element named  `'Image` but for some reason i'm not getting the desired result. It should extract 40 pages each with 10 images.

```
import scrapy
import json

class WineSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "SpidyWine"

url = 'https://maiscarrinho.com/api/search?q=vinho&pageNumber=%s&pageSize=10'
start_urls = [url % 1]
i = 1
def parse(self, response):
    data = json.loads(response.body.decode('utf-8'))
    for item in data['results']:
        yield {
            'Image': item.get('Image')
        }
        if item.get('Image'):
            WineSpider.i += 1
            yield scrapy.Request(self.url % WineSpider.i, callback=self.parse)
```